# How to use methods in MVC 3 aspx engineand how to use Repeater control in mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am a beginner in asp.net Mvc. i try to make some exercises to learn it. My samples in this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx

i make same sample using this link :

[image]

My VİEW :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" CodeBehind="~/Views/Product/ListProducts.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true"  Inherits="MvcAppExtNet.Views.Product.ListProducts" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    ListProducts
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<h2>ListProducts</h2>


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductList" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<%#Eval("Name") %>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</asp:Content>
```

MY CONTROLLER :

```
namespace MvcAppExtNet.Controllers
{
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Product/
       
        public void GetProduct()
        {
            List<Products> list = new List<Products>() { 
                new Products() { Id = 1, Name = "Hıyar" }, 
                new Products() { Id = 2, Name = "Kereviz" } };

            ViewData["Products"] = list;
        }

    }
}
```

if you look ListProducts.aspx.cs:

[image]

How to see my Repeater control(ProductList is a kind of repeater!!!!) on C#codes? Also how to use methods(Not Using ActionResult)? Thanks alot.

Comment: asp.net MVC is not asp.net webforms, to render data in a similar fashion as a repeater, you would write a `foreach` in your view file.

Comment: There's no databinding or server controls in MVC and that's really better that way. In MVC you pass a viewmodel to the view, and there you write the "display logic". I suggest you to go through the basics of Asp.Net MVC before using it for any real project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was tagged in ASP.NET MVC3 so I am going to answer it as such.

Go and work through the many tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc.  It is really an exciting framework, I prefer it to web forms.  Start with MVC3.

The way that it should be done is the controller gets a list of products from the database by doing a repository call.  The controller takes this list of products and passes it to the view.  The view will render it.  Basically this is how I would do it:

Product class:

```
public class Product
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My view model:

```
public class ProductListViewModel
{
     IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

In my action method in my controller I do a database call to return the products.  I then instantiate a new view model object and set the Products property to the list that was returned from the database:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
     ProductListViewModel viewModel = new ProductListViewModel
     {
          Products = productRepository.GetAllProducts()
     };

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in my view I would have the following:

```
<table>

@foreach(Product product in Model.Products)
{
     <tr>
          <td>Product Name:</td>
          <td>product.Name</td>
     </tr>
}

</table>
```

I hope I have cleared things up for you.  It's just a guideline, use it and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

MVC works a bit differently to web forms. You do not use  controls in your views and MVC does not have a repeater control. It has model binding and Razor, which gives you much more control.

With a bit of reading you should get your head around it soon. I would suggest you start [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

MVC 3 doesn't have controls and view state. If you are asking this question, then you are missing some fundamental knowledge regarding MVC pattern, therefore I suggest you work through tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc